# Use javascript lib from typescript (with inherited javascript dependencies)

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser, strophe, strophe.js

### Context

I am building a project in plain Typescript to communicate with a chat server. For the that communication I am using strophe.js lib.

Strophe lib comes in three flavors: *commonjs*, *esm* and *umd*. I do not really understand the difference between these formats, according to what I have searched:

- *commonjs* is for node
- *esm* for web apps
- *umd* is generic

Based on this I could use *esm* or *umd*, as this app is intended to run in the browser.

I wrote a Typescript file to act as a wrapper to strophe library. This is how I import it:

```js
import * as core from './dependencies/strophe.umd.js'; // using UMD
import core from './dependencies/strophe.esm.js'; // using ESM
const Strophe = core.Strophe;

// ...
// Usage example:
this.conn = new Strophe.Connection(options.connection, options.options);
```

### My problem

#### When using **ESM** format:

I can see the interface definition, call its functions, etc. Everything is great but the browser throws:
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "abab". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

#### When using **UMD** format:

Not errors shown at first, but Strophe is not being imported correctly. When trying to call connect function this error is thrown:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Connection' of undefined`

### Update

---

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-grass-sh4s9

To test this I run `tsc` and then `live-server` to serve the files

#### tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/recommended/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "build",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "paths": {
      "@core/*": ["./src/core"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Comment: If you recreate an example in something like [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) it's easier to help you.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-grass-sh4s9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It woule be a good idea to add Strophe.js as a dependency through a package manager like npm or Yarn. It looks like you have manually placed them in the folder called `dependencies`.

Adding the dependency: `yarn add strophe.js`
Adding the type declarations: `yarn add -D @types/strophe.js`

This would download Strophe.js into your `node_modules` folder.

Importing it in your code:

```
import { Strophe } from "strophe.js";
this.conn = new Strophe.Connection(options.connection, options.options);
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't have the strophe.js dependency. Although when I open the html in the browser this error is shown in console: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "strophe.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Comment: Great that you made a codesandbox! It looks like your current issue is not related to importing the Strophe.js dependency. At least I'm not seeing that issue in your codesandbox. If you're still having problems I'd suggest trimming down your codesandbox until it's the smallest reproducible version you can get, and then file a new question here on SO with that.

Comment: Also, would you mind accepting the answer, @adrisons?

Comment: I think it is related to the Strophe.js dependency, try to clic submit in the codesandbox. I will accept the answer when I can it work. You will receive the bounty anyway :)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/small-browser-4mgfv?file=/src/index.ts
This only seem to happen when there's no value for the `jid` field. I'm assuming it makes sense to have the button be a no-op if there's no value there. As for "working", I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here.